# How to change the point of rotation of bodies in BOX2d/LIBGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I have got a player set up and I am trying to make an arm for my character. The shapes are all created using either PolygonShapes or CircleShapes and I have made it so it points towards the mouse but I want to change the the point of rotation from this:

[image: img1]

to this:

[image: img2]

(Please forgive my crude drawings)

Comment: Do you want dynamic/physically-responsive motion of the individual shapes or only programmatic motion?

Comment: @LouisLangholtz All want for it is to rotate towards the mouse with the pivot point being elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i used a revolute joint which allowed to me set an anchor elsewhere, however, how do i rotate it towards the mouse position as the applyTorque method uses torque instead of radians?